# Bluetooth stops working on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I am using a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro with Ubuntu Gnome. I think I started with 14.10 on this laptop, and kept upgrading and I am on 17.04 now. All along, I never had a comfortable use of bluetooth devices.

When I do a cold boot, I get them working - typically one or two of headphones, mouse and keyboard -  but they stop typically after a few minutes. It does not seem like there is a set timeout, although I cannot rule out this possibility completely if the timeout is associated with inactivity. I believe I browsed most of the answers online, and couldn't find a solution.

`sudo service bluetooth status`:

```
 bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-05-15 09:46:39 EDT; 2h 0min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1672 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1672 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 15 11:22:38 Sencer bluetoothd[1672]: Can't get HIDP connection info
May 15 11:22:38 Sencer bluetoothd[1672]: connect: No route to host (113)
May 15 11:23:08 Sencer bluetoothd[1672]: Can't get HIDP connection info
May 15 11:23:08 Sencer bluetoothd[1672]: connect: No route to host (113)
May 15 11:23:38 Sencer bluetoothd[1672]: Can't get HIDP connection info
May 15 11:23:38 Sencer bluetoothd[1672]: connect: No route to host (113)
May 15 11:24:08 Sencer bluetoothd[1672]: Can't get HIDP connection info
May 15 11:24:08 Sencer bluetoothd[1672]: connect: No route to host (113)
May 15 11:24:40 Sencer bluetoothd[1672]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
May 15 11:25:28 Sencer bluetoothd[1672]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
```

`rfkill list`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Have you found any useful information in your log files? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingBluetooth

Comment: syslog essentially gives same output as `service status` I copied above. the only addition line is `May 15 10:37:58 Sencer bluetoothd[1672]: connect error: Device or resource busy (16)`.